# Computed properties with ember-model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I have a simple model that worked with ember-data but not sure how to get this to work with ember-model?

```
Acme.App = Ember.Model.extend(
  post_screenshot_url: Ember.attr()

  post_screenshot_url_thumb: (->
    @get('post_screenshot_url') + '/?thumb=true'
  ).property('')

)
```

This used to work with ember-data but now this doesn't work with ember-model. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me with latest Ember and Ember Model, check this JSBin:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/obeHimU/3/edit?html,js,output

PS: You probably should add "post_screenshot_url" to the properties call on "post_screenshot_url_thumb" so it gets correctly updated.